# How to sort List by containing text using LINQ

Tags: c#

In my list I have string with name and surname, how do I sort it by strings that contains X surname?

For example:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
            {
               new Student("John Doe"),
               new Student("Lucy Novak")
            };
```

With output: Students with surname Doe: John Doe

Comment: When you say "sort", do you mean "filter"? Sorting is an operation that keeps all rows and changes the order they appear `students.OrderBy(student => student.Name.Contains(" Doe") ? 0 : 1) //put 'Doe's at the top`. Filtering is an operation that removes rows that do not match a  criteria e.g. `students.Where(student => student.Name.Contains(" Doe")) //remove anyone not called Doe`

Comment: Why you don't separate forename and surname?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQ877O

Comment: @RandRandom: This fails for people like [John Davison Rockefeller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._Rockefeller)

Comment: @Luuk - yes, indeed, but it has homework vibes and doesn't seem to be 100% fool proof

Answer (score 0):

If you want *filter out* students with the *second name* `Doe` you can put:

```
 var result = 
   .Where(student => student
      .Name
      .Split(' ', 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .ElementAtOrDefault(1) == "Doe")
   .ToList();
```

if you want to get *all* students, but sort them in such a way, that `"Doe"` are on the top:

```
 var result = 
   .OrderBy(student => student
      .Name
      .Split(' ', 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .ElementAtOrDefault(1) != "Doe")
   .ToList();
```

Note `!=` - we can order by `bool`, but we have `false < true`

In both cases we `Split` stundent's `Name` into at most `3` parts (first name, second name, all the rest names if they are). Then we try to obtain second name by `.ElementAtOrDefault(1)` and compare it (or `null` if student doen't have second name) with `Doe`